# min & max of values in looped-thru JSON data (no jQuery)

Tags: javascript, json

In the following:

```
function processResponse(response){
    var myObj = JSON.parse(response); // convert string to object
    var weighInData = myObj["WEIGH-INS"];
    var dataRows = document.getElementById("data-rows");
    dataRows.innerHTML = "";

    for (var obj in weighInData) {
        if (weighInData[obj].user === selUser) { // *
            var weights = JSON.parse("[" + weighInData[obj].weight + "]"); // convert to object
            var row = "<tr>" +
                            "<td class=\"date\">" + weighInData[obj].date + " </td>" +
                            "<td class=\"value\">" + weighInData[obj].weight + "</td>" +
                        "</tr>";
            var userDisplayEl = document.getElementById("user-display");
            userDisplayEl.innerHTML = weighInData[obj].user;
            output.innerHTML += row;
        } // if ... === selUser
    } // for var obj in weighInData
} // processResponse
```

- if (weighInData[obj].user === selUser) { ... returns the following (using example Ron):

  Object { user="Ron", date="2014-08-01", weight="192"}

  Object { user="Ron", date="2014-08-02", weight="195"}

  Object { user="Ron", date="2014-08-03", weight="198"} ... etc.

... so my problem presently is where this belongs:
    var peakWeight = Math.max.apply(Math, weights);
    console.log("peakWeight: " + peakWeight);

Since I'm only after the weight values for the matching user, I assumed it would have to run within the 'if (weighInData[obj].user === selUser) { ... ', but this (and numerous other attempts in and out of the loop, including a for loop within the selUser) fail to achieve the desired results. In fact, even when the math function wasn't running on each value in 'weights', (i.e., outside the loop) and only ran outside the loop, the result was an incorrect value.

Any insight is greatly appreciated,

svs

Comment: During the for loop, I'd suggest storing the weight value of each object into an array (object that matches selUser).  After the for loop, all weight values will be in the array and you should easily be able to find the min/max values from there.  Would code surrounding this example help?

Comment: @Will Thank you Will, and yes indeed an example with my (otherwise painfully learned, working) code as context would be greatly appreciated :) Cheers,svs

Comment: @Will p.s. you said: "I'd suggest storing the weight value of each object into an array (object that matches selUser)." Is that not what I'm doing with this: var weights = JSON.parse("[" + weighInData[obj].weight + "]") ? Thx,svs

Comment: No, you are getting the value and storing it into a variable (which gets overwritten each time we finding a matching obj).  From my below example, you can add or "push" that variable weights into the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a very simple example you can probably adjust to fit your purpose:

```
// create this array outside of for loop so it already exists
var arr = []; 

// test data
var a = { user:"Ron", date:"2014-08-01", weight:"192"};
var b = { user:"Ron", date:"2014-08-02", weight:"195"};
var c = { user:"Ron", date:"2014-08-03", weight:"198"};        

// within for loop, you should only need to push once (per loop)
arr.push( a.weight );
arr.push( b.weight );
arr.push( c.weight );

// after the loop ends, display loop, get max and display
alert(arr);
var peakWeight = Math.max.apply(null, arr);
var minWeight = Math.min.apply(null, arr);
alert("Max: " + peakWeight + " -- Min: " + minWeight);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/biz79/sb7zayze/

If i were to edit your code, something like this might work:

```
function processResponse(response){
    var myObj = JSON.parse(response); // convert string to object
    var weighInData = myObj["WEIGH-INS"];
    var dataRows = document.getElementById("data-rows");
    dataRows.innerHTML = "";

    // ADDED: create array
    var arr = [];  

    for (var obj in weighInData) {
        if (weighInData[obj].user === selUser) { // *
            var weights = JSON.parse("[" + weighInData[obj].weight + "]"); // convert to object

            // ADDED:  add to array
            arr.push(weights);

            var row = "<tr>" +
                            "<td class=\"date\">" + weighInData[obj].date + " </td>" +
                            "<td class=\"value\">" + weighInData[obj].weight + "</td>" +
                        "</tr>";
            var userDisplayEl = document.getElementById("user-display");
            userDisplayEl.innerHTML = weighInData[obj].user;
            output.innerHTML += row;
        } // if ... === selUser
    } // for var obj in weighInData

  // ADDED: after the loop ends, display loop, get max/min and display
  alert(arr);
  var peakWeight = Math.max.apply(null, arr);
  var minWeight = Math.min.apply(null, arr);
  alert("Max: " + peakWeight + " -- Min: " + minWeight);       

} // processResponse
```

Comment: yup, that's precisely how I implemented your (pre-edit) answer. (Alternatively, arr.push(weighInData[obj].weight) without first setting the 'weights' var). Many thanks again, and I'll be able to use this also for min value. Cheers! svs